# What are possible reconstruction cost functions for Variational Auto-encoders?

Tags: variational-bayes, cross-entropy

In almost most papers and tutorials about VAEs, the *reconstruction loss* term is shown in this, Bernouli ditribution cross entropy form:

$$
C=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x} (y\ln(x) + (1-y)\ln(1-x))
$$

However, it is usually said that other cost functions are also possible. What are they, and what requirements they should meet, because the math behind VAEs is derived from approximating probabilities?

Can, for example, one use usual square error: $||x-y||^2$, or mean-square-error one? How will the different magnitude of values induced by this (different) error term interfere with the training process?

Thank you!

#### Context notes

I'm trying to make it work for continuous, non-normalized values in the range outside $[0, 1]$, including negative values.

Comment: It would help to state what you want to use such a VAE for. The reconstruction loss for a VAE is of the above form because typically we are trying to minimize the discrepancy between the true sample distribution and the generative distribution. In this sense it's a KL divergence between the two distributions.See here for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05908

Comment: In this particular case it's a chemical data, and consist of large vectors of real values outside of [0,1] range as stated in the question. I've read this paper _many_ times! Isn't the _latent loss_ term based on the KL-divergence, not the reconstruction one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mean squared error, but it's very hard to optimize. You are probably better off normalizing your data to fall between 0 and 1 and then using binary crossentropy.